# Excel: Find rows with matching data except for 1 column

Tags: excel, exception, match

I have an Excel sheet with thousands of rows in it. It has 3 columns: name, date and yes/no.

Please see this image for the example:

[image]

I'm looking for pairs of rows which are duplicate in column A & B, but have different values in column C. In my example above, rows 1&7 is a pair while rows 3&4 is not.

Is there a way in Excel to highlight all of the pairs, delete all rows which are not part of a pair or some other way for me to recognize the pairs?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to concatenate all three into one line in column D `=CONCATENATE(A1,B1,C1)`. Then do a conditional format of matching values on column D. After that Sort by color and delete what is no longer needed.